# Element cannot be scrolled into view with Selenium hub and firefox remote Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-hub

I am using Selenium Hub with a remote firefox driver. I'm experiencing an error when trying to click on an element after hovering on it (via `Actions.moveToElement()` method).

For context, my approach *does* allow me to click on the element just once. But after several steps, when I want to click on that element again (using my hover method again), doing so fails.

When I try this locally, by running it via firefox in headless mode, it works without problems.

I've also tried utilizing `JS scrollIntoView()` method, but this doesn't help. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Great question! Actions + interactions with selenium can be tricky to navigate, both literally and figuratively! **Q for you:** which programming language are you operating in? _(Selenium is widely used across many languages.)_

Comment: I am using Java 8